# How to find partial duplicates?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have table with a two NVARCHAR columns : source and target.

**I want to find the rows for which you can find another row with the same source and a target containing the current one.**

In the example below, I want to find rows 1 and 7 :

- Row 1 is "partial duplicate" of Row 3
- Row 7 is "partial duplicate" of Row 6

Here is a snippet of SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (ID int, [source] nvarCHAR(12), [target] nvarCHAR(12))

INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[source],[target]) VALUES (1,'wordA','word1')
INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[source],[target]) VALUES (2,'wordA','word2')
INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[source],[target]) VALUES (3,'wordA','word3 ; word1')
INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[source],[target]) VALUES (4,'wordB','word4')
INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[source],[target]) VALUES (5,'wordC','word5')
INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[source],[target]) VALUES (6,'wordD','word6 ; word7')
INSERT INTO #YourTable ([ID],[source],[target]) VALUES (7,'wordD','word7')

SELECT 
  [source],
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [target]
    FROM #YourTable 
    WHERE ([source] = Results.[source]) 
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS NameValues
FROM #YourTable Results
GROUP BY [source]
HAVING COUNT(1)>1

DROP TABLE #YourTable
```

My first idea was to concatenate but it doesn't get me any closer to the solution...

I could export my data to a CSV and work with a programming language (python, C#, ...) to isolate the IDs, but I am curious to see how it can be done within SQL.

**The ultimate goal is to remove the "partial duplicates".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your job can be done using the `exists` operator:

```
delete
  from #yourtable   t1
 where exists (
          select 1
            from #yourtable t2
           where t2.source = t1.source
             and t2.target <> t1.target
             and t2.target like t1.target || '%'
       )
     ;
```

Comment: I changed `and t2.target like t1.target || '%'` to `and (t2.[target ] like '%'+t1.[target ]+'%' or t2.[target ] like t1.[target ]+'%' or t2.[target ] like '%'+t1.[target ])`.

Comment: `and (t2.[target ] like '%'+t1.[target ]+'%'` will suffice as `'%'` matches the empty string (which is the reason for having `and t2.target <> t1.target` inside the `where` clause)